# Is is possible for a humanoid to have a quasi-realistic explanation for having a limited form of super strength and agility?

Tags: science-fiction, humanoid, strength

In terms of strength I am thinking of launching people over five feet with a single blow or just by throwing them

In terms of agility I am picturing the average action hero

Baring the explanations through high gravity on the planet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The simple answer is "yes, there are numerous that have already been described in fiction, but if there were a real-world way to do it, you'd see such a thing in the military and olympics." What, specifically, prevents those from being an adequate answer?

Answer (score 1):

## [Double-null myostatin](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.94.23.12457)

Myostatin is a thing that puts a limit on the growth of muscles. Normal people have 1-2 copies of a gene that produces it. Some individual animals have 0 copies, leading to super-strength.   This mutation has been identified in mice and cattle. Humans have the same genetics but I don't believe there's been a verified case of a human with the mutation.

Comment: There were pictures of a toddler with a six pack (the muscles, not the beer conveyance package) floating around the internet a few years ago. Whether this was single or double-null I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Sure

1. Increased muscle mass, you don't even need to go superhuman just peak human. Pretty sure the actor who plays the mountain could easily throw someone 5 feet.
2. Strong bones
   Genetc alteration or perhaps cybornetic implants.
   How ever it was done increasing bones strength even a little bit will dramatically increase how much you can lift.
3. Removing safe guards:
   You has built in safe guards to limited how fast or how strong you are, outside of a life endangering situation, inorder to prevent ingery.

If you genetically remove these safe guards then you could get access to seemingly superhuman strength and speed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at Nature - a Chimp has approximately 1.35 times the Strength of a Human. a Gorilla has the strength of over double a Human - They can lift/throw upwards of 815 Kg.

I'd say they are pretty 'Humanoid' and they exist - it's a combination of different ratios of Muscle fibres, different skeletal structures, greater muscle mass, different tendon structure etc. etc. [This Reddit post has some excellent points](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/60tu6d/why_are_gorillas_so_ripped_they_sit_around_all/)

So, with a little change to a Human's bone, muscle and Tendon structure - you could have superhuman strength.